# Printf format specifiers

Tags: c

I've been trying to cobble together the format of `printf` into a sort of linear format. Is the following a correct understanding of the possible `printf` formats?

```
% <justification: [-]?> <sign: [ +]?>  <alternate: [#]?> 
  <padding: [0? num]?> <precision: [.num]?> <modifier: [h|hh|l|ll|L|z|t|j]?>
  <format: [c|d(i)|e(E)|f|o|p|x(X)|u|s|g(G)]>
```

Is the order and meanings correct in the above? A couple examples being:

```
printf(" %-10.3s %-+20ld", "Hello!", 14L);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the following a correct understanding of the possible printf formats?

"Generally" yes, but for example you "can't" do `%jg` or like `%0#p`.

There is also `%n`.

Both "precision" and "padding" may be asterisks, like `%*s` or `%.*s` (but you could have defined `num` as `([0-9]+|\*)`...).

Also `.` is optionally followed by a number. So it's more like `<precision: [. num? ]>` - if only `.` is specified, precision is taken as zero.

> Is the order

The order of `- +#0` is irrelevant and you can repeat them, so you can `%-+020d` and `%+0-+++000----20d` with same meaning (and `0` is ignored when used with `-`, so also there are corner cases).

> meanings correct in the above?

There is no explanation in the above. `-` is not "justification" (taken literally, a word?), it's a flag that makes the output be **left** justified *within the field*. Also meaning depends on context - "precision" for floats maybe can be understood as the number of digits after comma, but "precision of a string" sounds strange. But generally, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Your specification is too restrictive:

- the flags `+`, `-`, `#`, `0` and space can appear in any order, but some combinations are meaning less, such as `%+s`.
- width and precision can be specified as `*`
- `a` and `A` were introduced to produce hexadecimal floating point representations
- `F` is available and different from `f` for NaNs and infinities.
- `%%` and `%n` should be recognised too.

Here is a regular expression to match all valid `printf` conversion specifications, but that will not detect invalid combinations:

```
%[ +-#0]*{[*]|[1-9][0-9]*}?(.{[*]|[0-9]*}?)?{h|hh|l|ll|L|z|t|j}?[%naAcdieEfFopxXusgG]
```

You might refine it to reject any flags for `%%` and restrict other cases too, but it will become quite complicated to express as a regex.

Comment: thanks, that regex is pretty cool and seems like it would cover most edge cases, so be a good reference, knowing that some edge cases wouldn't be covered and probably couldn't be covered in a sane regex. Thanks!

Comment: @samuelbrody1249: the regex will accept all legal conversion specifications, but will also accept many incorrect ones such as `%1%`, `%+s`, `%llG`...